# Pre-loading TimescaleDB on Spilo container

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I'm using the postgres operator with the Spilo build `spilo-11:1.5-p7`.

How do I configure it to preload the timescaledb library?

I've tried using sed to alter the [config file](https://github.com/zalando/spilo/blob/cf95f6c12692f422b1730696ed052385304a936a/postgres-appliance/scripts/configure_spilo.py#L227) like so:

```
sed -i "s/bg_mon,/bg_mon,timescaledb,/" /scripts/configure_spilo.py
```

But this does not work, because it is being run at the build time of the Dockerfile, which seems to be too early.  Is there any way to get this to run after the expansion of the compressed contents, but before postgres is run?  Some kind of script callback?

Comment: I should add, that I tried and was not able to do a build of a modified version of the Spilo image with the necessary mods made by hand.

Comment: timescaledb was added to the shared_preload_libraries recently: https://github.com/zalando/spilo/pull/326 . Can you try the latest version?

Comment: What's the command to activate this extension? I can't find docs for it in spilo? It's not active by default.